# Showing that $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{m-1}-x^{n-1}}{1-x}dx$ is convergent if $ 0<m<1 , 0<n <1$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

> Showing that $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{m-1}-x^{n-1}}{1-x}dx$ is convergent if $ 0<m<1 , 0<n <1$

Let $I = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{m-1}-x^{n-1}}{1-x}dx$ then $I = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{m-1}}{1-x}dx -  \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n-1}}{1-x}dx$

We consider $I_1 =  \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{m-1}}{1-x}dx$

Let $f_1(x) = \frac{x^{m-1}}{1-x}$ then $f_1(x)$ has three points of discontinuity at $x = 0,1 ,\infty$ if $0<m<1$

Let us consider $g_1(x) =  \frac{1}{x^{1-m}}$ then  $\lim_{x \to 0+}\frac{f_1(x)}{g_1(x)} = 1$
Now the integral of the function $g_1(x)$ from $0$ to $a(<1)$ is convergent so the $\int_{0}^{a}f_1(x)dx$ is convergent.

Now we consider the function $f_1(x)$ at the point $x = 1$ then we consider the function $g_1(x) = 1-x$ then $\lim_{x \to 1+}\frac{f_1(x)}{g_1(x)} = \frac{1-x}{x^{m-1}(1-x)} = 1$

Now we see that the function $\int_{a}^{1}g(x) = \int_{a}^{1}\frac{1}{1-x}dx $ is not convergent so the integral $\int_{a}^{1}f_1(x)dx$ is not convergent.

Where am I going wrong in this step?

Comment: Where you're going wrong is that $\int \frac{x^{m-1}}{1-x}$ is not absolutely convergent (it is conditionally). This is because for $x = 1+h$, the denominator vanishes linearly, but the numerator is about $1$, but in any case this makes the strategy of breaking to these integrals ineffective. However, the initial integral has $x^{m-1} - x^{n-1},$ and this numerator also vanishes around $1$, which saves the convergence bacon. Indeed, for $x = 1+h$, $|h| \ll 1,$ the difference behaves roughly as $(m-n)h$ (by Taylor expansion), and this nicely cancels with the linear behaviour in the denominator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to show that the integral is convergent is by cutting the integral into three parts

\begin{align}
\int^{1/2}_0 + \int^{3/2}_{1/2} +  \int^\infty_{3/2}\frac{x^{m-1}-x^{n-1}}{1-x}d x = I_1+I_2+I_3.
\end{align}
It is clear that $I_3$ is convergent since
\begin{align}
I_3 \le C\int^\infty_{3/2}\left(\frac{1}{x^{2-m}}+\frac{1}{x^{2-n}}\right)dx<\infty
\end{align}
for some constant $C>0$.

It is also clear that $I_1$ is convergent since
\begin{align}
I_1 \le C\int^{1/2}_0 \left(\frac{1}{x^{1-m}}+\frac{1}{x^{1-n}}\right)dx.
\end{align}

Lastly, let us deal with $I_2$. Assume $n\ge m$. Notice by the mean value theorem, we have that
\begin{align}
I_2 = \int^{3/2}_{1/2} x^{m-1}\frac{1-x^{n-m}}{1-x} \le C\int^{3/2}_{1/2} x^{m-1} d x
\end{align}

Comment: Which mean value theorem are we using? I don't understand that part of $I_2$

Comment: We apply MVT to  $f(x) = x^{n-m}$ to get $f(1)-f(x) = f'(\xi)(1-x)$. Notice that $f'(x)$ is bounded on $[1/2, 3/2]$.